# Probability of a point taken from a multivariate normal distribution will be farther away from the mean than some other point.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

Let $Y\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2 I_k)$, where $\mu\in \mathbb{R}^k$, then what is:

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\lvert \lvert Y - \mu \rvert \rvert _2 \geq \lvert \lvert Y - Z \rvert \rvert_2 \right),$$
where $Z$ is an element of $\mathbb{R}^k$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint (geometric intuition).** the set $\{y \in \mathbb{R}^k : \|y - \mu\|_2 \ge \|y - Z\|_2\}$ is a half-space of $\mathbb{R}^k$ whose boundary is the hyperplane $\{y \in \mathbb{R}^k : \|y- \mu\|_2 = \|y - Z\|_2\}$ that is the "perpendicular bisector" of the segment connecting $\mu$ and $Z$. Another way to think about this hyperspace is that it contains the point $(\mu + Z)/2$ and has normal vector $Z-\mu$.

**Hint (reduce to a simpler problem).** Consider the simpler case where $Z = (\mu_1 + z_1, \mu_2, \ldots, \mu_k)$ where $z_1 > 0$. ($Z$ differs from $\mu$ only in the first component.) Then
$$P(\|Y - \mu \|_2 \ge \|Y - Z\|_2) = P(Y_1 \ge \mu_1 + \frac{1}{2} z_1) = 1 - \Phi(z_1/(2 \sigma)).$$
For the original problem, use rotational symmetry of the distribution of $Y$ to reduce to this simpler case.